# Chrome Extension Asynchronous SendMessage not Resolving with sendResponse()

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am running into a unique issue trying to use `async chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`

If I understand correctly, running this function asynchronously will wait for sendResponse from the backend to resolve. I want to send a message that triggers a tab update (url navigation) and listens for this update to complete before sending the response. My issue is sending the response from the (nested?) update listener. It doesnt seem to resolve the original message listener despite the response being sent. Here is my current attempt:

**backround.ts:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  (
    message: { action: string; url?: string; tabId?: number },
    sender,
    sendResponse
  ) => {

    if (message.action === "navigate" && message.url) {

      (async () => {
        const navigateListener = (tabId: number, changeInfo: any) => {
          if (changeInfo.status === "complete") {
            sendResponse("Navigation Complete");
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(navigateListener); // Cleanup listener
          }
        };

        // Register listener before initiating navigation to avoid missing the event
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(navigateListener);

        const activeTab = await getActiveTabId();

        chrome.tabs.update(activeTab, { url: message.url }, (tab) => {
          console.log("Updating tab...");
          // If the tab cannot be updated or the URL is loaded instantly, consider additional handling
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !tab) {
            console.error("Navigation failed or tab was closed.");
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(navigateListener); // Cleanup listener if necessary
          }
        });
      })();

      return true;
    }
  }
);
```

**content_script.ts:**

```
    const navMessage: NavigateMessage = {
      action: "navigate",
      url: `https://www.example.com`,
      tabId,
    };

    const navRes = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(navMessage);
```

As you can see I am returning true within the listener to signal that I want this to run asynchronously. I am also getting the response logged from my backround so it is definitly sending a response. Additionally, this works if I move the `sendResponse()` from inside the update listener to the outer message listener.

**If this is not a solvable problem with my current approach. How can I achieve the desired effect?**

Comment: When the active tab is navigated the old environment is destroyed along with your content script, so there's no one to receive the response. It works when calling sendResponse immediately simply because it returns right before navigation. The entire code seems overly complicated, why can't you use just use location.href = url? Is the purpose to navigate a different tab? In that case why do you use getActiveTabId instead of tabId in the message and how is that tabId is obtained? Why don't you use sender.tab.id?

Comment: @wOxxOm You're right, sender.tab.id is a way better way of accomplishing getting the tab. I am also now using window.location.href for navigation. I was under the impression only the background service could handle navigate hence the complex code. Thanks! Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?